# How does IntelliJ IDEA implement an interrupt mechanism like Visual Basic?

Tags: vba, intellij-idea

Is it necessary to develop an interrupt mechanism for IDEA?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the official guide on how to ask a question; https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This will help you avoid frustration and get you on track to good answers!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.